# Build a deployable jar in a multi-module project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am having a project structure like this:

```
parent/
  server/    - Spring Boot Application
    pom.xml
  client-1/  - Angular Web Application
    pom.xml
  client-2/  - Angular Web Application
    pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

I am able to  build this application where the Spring Boot Application is a `jar`, which contains the two Angular clients in its `static/` folder.

However, currently the Spring Boot Application's `pom.xml` has to know about the clients and I would like to move this to the parent.

Here I am lacking some Maven skills though.

---

This is what should happen:

1. Build Web Clients
2. Build Spring Boot Application
3. Copy web clients to `static/`

I am currently using the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the client content but I noticed that there is an issue - if the clients are not build already, then it will copy nothing into the final `jar` which means the web clients are missing for deployment.

Right now, this is the `pom.xml` of the parent:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mz</groupId>
    <artifactId>mz-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>mz-server</module>
        <module>mz-admin</module>
        <module>mz-web</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

How can I accomplish this?

---

Below is how I am currently building the `jar` using `maven-resources-plugin`. But as stated, in this case the server project has to know about the clients and also this does not guarantee that the clients are getting build first.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${build.directory}/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../mz-admin/dist</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-web</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${build.directory}/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../mz-web/dist</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `client-1` and `client-2` as dependency to your `server` project. That will ensure your clients are built before your server and the files are available.

Comment: I did that - but `server` is always built first. The `jar` file gets created and only after that the other clients get built.

Comment: That's not how maven dependency works. Maven always builds the dependent after the dependency. At least, as far as I have worked with maven.

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake. The dependencies get build in the correct order with this.